# Is it really better to “A/B test” everything in lieu of understanding usability research?

Tags: gui-design, collaboration

Have you worked with people who don’t believe in learning from UI research and instead going with their own beliefs? Were you able to convince them that bad ideas are bad ideas before time is wasted implementing two versions of it?

Myself, I would imagine that it is monstrously wasteful to have to learn *everything* the hard way instead of using the research done by usability experts over the years. Am I wrong? Or, how can I share this insight effectively?

Answer (score 2):

In my career path I ran into a few people who didn't really understand values of UX or UX practices. My answer would be they all are individuals and their reasons are individual, too, so in my cases I addressed each case separately.

As for the A/B testing, as any specialised tool, it has lot's of limitations. I would take the data gotten from it with grain of salt.

There is a serious number of issues listed here:
http://www.qubitproducts.com/sites/default/files/pdf/most_winning_ab_test_results_are_illusory.pdf

A more crude post on the main issues of believing A/B Testing is an universal strategy http://danwaldschmidt.com/2014/09/business/ab-testing-idiots

And I personally love this answer on Quora that pretty much sums it all up. http://qr.ae/qJBEP

This all being said, there is still a possibility your colleague's idea is legit, and fits the case, as you didn't disclose any of the context.

Comment: Started reading the pdf you linked. Based on that the proper answer to this question would be: "By helping them do A/B testing better." Next time doing A/B testing gets relevant just helpfully point out that you found some studies with great advice on how to get more accurate results from A/B testing. Doing A/B more accurately -> Understanding its limitations -> Appreciating alternatives more.

Comment: Ville, I think some limitations are unavoidable in some cases. For example, a small service might not have enough users to make a sample — there is no way to make a quick workaround for that.

Comment: Obviously, but the question is about educating peers about alternatives to A/B testing, not about improving A/B testing. The fact that limitations of A/B testing would become easily apparent is **not** a downside for that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's reverse the question. How would a colleague be able to convince YOU that your ideas are not good and that time shouldn't be spent mocking up your ideas?

What evidence would you need? Their opinion obviously would not convince you to say. "Yeah. You're right. What a silly idea."

I would gather that articles and books by recognized authorities would be the very least necessary for you to begin to question your ideas. The same (perhaps / probably / hopefully) for them.